# Issues Getting Xml in ActiveReports

Tags: c#, activereports

I feel like this should be really easy, so I'm probably missing something. If my Detail section's Recordset Pattern is //Record, how do I access the specific Record node in the Format event for this section? I can see all of the Xml from this.DataSource, but I want whichever specific Record node that I am formatting at the given time.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a global index, I am able to track which node I use by incrementing it each time it hits the Detail_Format event.

Example:

```
 int i = 0;

 private void Detail_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string thisIsWhatIWanted = (this.DataSource as XMLDataSource).NodeList[i].OuterXml;
      i++;
 }
```

Hope that helps anyone with a similar issue.